# If I in my specifications explained enough where someone can recreate my invention but broad in claims could that pass in the uspto?

Tags: claims, specification

If my description has enough detail such that someone in the field could recreate it without problems, but my claims ( the part which is the real protect ) are broad to make it hard for infringers. Will this be rejected?

For example lets say I invented the stop light. I mention I have created a signaling device with changing lights to control traffic. The lights are red, yellow and green. But in my claims I just say a traffic controlling device with lights. Could this hold up in court even if someone invented around my description but not my claims? Could I win in court or even get that claim passed?

Comment: You can always try to be broad and narrow as necessary to get the patent approved. If you are too broad, you will likely run in to prior art. Unlike the specification, the claims can be amended.